# Future.delayed execution

Tags: dart

Got some example.

```
void main() {
  A a = A();
  transform(a);
  print(a.str + ' sync');
}

Future<void> transform(A a) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => a.str = 'B');
  print(a.str + ' async');
}

class A {
  String str = 'A';
}
```

And output:

```
A sync
B async
```

And next example

```
void main() {
  A a = A();
  transform(a);
  print(a.str + ' sync');
}

Future<void> transform(A a) async {
  Function f = () {
    a.str = 'B';
  };
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), f());
  print(a.str + ' async');
}

class A {
  String str = 'A';
}
```

With output:

```
B sync
B async
```

Am i right thinking that f() is executed but just not returned in the second case, so i've got the a.str value modified imidiatly and returned later? Or what the right answer?

Comment: In your second example you are calling the function `f` immediately since you are writing `f()`. The returned value of this execution are then used as the second argument for `Future.delayed`. If you want to provide the function as a parameter to `Future.delayed` you should use `f` (without the `()`).

Comment: I thought Function f=(){a.str='B';}; only declares f(), cause commenting // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3),f()); gives me A async
A sync

Comment: It is not the declaration there is a problem with. It is how you refer to the function afterwards. The function is saved inside a variable named `f`. If you do `()` on the variable, you execute the function which `f` refers to. :)

Comment: oh/excuse me. i didnt read your first comment attentively. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I have posted an answer you can accept if we are done. Please just tell me if there are more details you need help with related to this question. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the second example you have the following line:

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), f());
```

What you are doing here is executing the function pointed at by the variable `f` and uses the result from this method as the second argument to `Future.delaye`. The reason for this is that you have `()` right after the name of the variable `f`, which is used to indicate you want to execute the method pointed at by `f` without any arguments.

What you should have done instead (if you want to send the function itself as the second argument for `Future.delayed`) is just use `f`:

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), f);
```

Comment: I know, i just thought that await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), f()) begans execution of f() after 3 seconds, but it seems that it executes it immideatily and just returns the result after 3 seconds.

Comment: @ArtT Yes. Because the `await` is using the await on the returned future from executing `Future.delayed`. So `Future.delayed` is executed, returns a future and we await on that. So all parameters to `Future.delayed` is being resolved before calling `Future.delayed`. And in your case, doing `f()` means you want to execute `f` and use the returned value as parameter to `Future.delayed`.

Answer (score 0):

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3),(){f();});
```

here what i wanted

Comment: What you are doing here is providing a new function (without immediately executing it) as argument to `Future.delayed` which later calls `f()`. This example is more or less the same as if you have just provided `f` as argument as my suggested solution.